# Single sign-on to Azure portal

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, portal

Is there any option to sign-in to Azure portal using clientID, client Secret, Tenant ID and /or subscription ID? Most of the samples I saw are using AD or SAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

If you get the sign in url of the azure portal, you will find it uses [this flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#protocol-diagram-access-token-acquisition) to authorize.

[image]

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c&
response_mode=form_post&
response_type=code+id_token&
scope=https%3a%2f%2fmanagement.core.windows.net%2f%2fuser_impersonation+openid+email+profile&
state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3d5sSBWCgxO8uzYlVgeWTBnBpO_3udn25WSlg2P5mZjzotjbc0u3aiZfTvDwyVNboeIldUVKig-KNmc_LiG_a2LI4dySYHViQ1bEQgXUt1c7PbCQ4Nqg-VOu9nsnSwTZ4i15w_0XeNah_PvG8B0TgQI5D-AlN4lhNrwtjN8ATClowc38Ifdu7h8BweU3sGvxlvYxtBG3-VzwSty-jaDbz3CRTUFmm0jTTKOGPrHsGu3q6-R9pDKFqvZk50Cd6AstdLe4qpcTRxFlkb114JxGW0BzZKIy__sIbqkHm_WeMnaFBGuQaTcGv4e7EizLxbZUc_jpqopZRCw7sfv-eaxHrD_ZoaXzNtylfoVnfcrnK0cbvh1TopnOcY166ZFW4uQlFu73De9SPMKMVr53gaUJTfR_pdJBQ_hS51L4quMf_noP4x5szhQ314hxgwoJBnw7R_8vhBKF6jplZmhqf3Hrsp4nEyzjjbyocCoXF9qxJjLkY&
nonce=637188980051547113.OTZkOTdlYjctODJiNS00M2E1LWFjZWUtM2FlMTUyYmJmOTc0ZWUxOWQ1OTYtNTBhOC00ZTc0LWFmMGYtNDkwYTA3ODJkZmEx&
redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fportal.azure.com%2fsignin%2findex%2f%3ffeature.refreshtokenbinding%3dtrue%26feature.snivalidation%3dtrue%26feature.usemsallogin%3dtrue&site_id=501430&client-request-id=c171ca99-bd9c-4a38-aaa0-a9344d273131&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=1.0.40306.1554
```

Actually the azure portal is an AD App registered in azure ad, so you need the user account to login.

[image]

If you want to use the service principal(i.e. the clientID you mentioned) to do operations on the azure resources, you could use the Azure [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-2.8.0), [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest), [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).

**Samples:**

1.[Use the service principal to login Azure powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-2.8.0#sign-in-with-a-service-principal-)

```
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString <use a secure password here> -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('service principal name/id', $passwd)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $tenantId
```

2.[Use the service principal to login Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-login)

```
az login --service-principal -u http://azure-cli-2016-08-05-14-31-15 -p VerySecret --tenant contoso.onmicrosoft.com
```

3.Use the client credential flow to get the token, then use it to call the REST API, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#client-credentials-grant-non-interactive-clients).